# How do I find out what template WP is using?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using some complicated theme that a client installed and you know how each theme does their own thing. Some call multiple parts of pages and such.

Anyway, I cant figure out what template is generating the blog posts of a theme I'm having to edit. The body class isn't helping either and searching by a CSS class or ID isnt either as its a very complicated theme with like 20 folders and over 100 php files.

Is there a way to have it echo out what template it is using?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37292/how-do-you-find-out-which-template-page-is-serving-the-current-page